Computing an integral using differential under the integral sign
The following integral is in question.
$$I(x) =\int_0^x \frac{\ln(1+tx)}{1+t^2}\,dt$$
My attempt is finding $I’(x)$ which is
$$I’(x) = \int_0^x \frac{t}{(1+t^2)(1+tx)}\,dt + \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2} $$
Now we can use partial fraction decompostion for the first integral.
$$\frac{t}{(1+t^2)(1+tx)} = \frac{At +B}{1+t^2}+\frac{C}{1+tx}$$
Solving this gives the following values:
$$A = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
$$B = \frac{x}{1+x^2}$$
$$C = \frac{-x}{1+x^2}$$
Now we can solve the first integral and we obtain that
$$I’(x) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2} + \frac{x\arctan(x)}{1+x^2}$$
Here Intuitively I would get something that is easy to integrate and find the constant by limits or some other obvious way but I get a function that I cannot integrate, can someone help me and give me a hint of what I am doing wrong ? Thanks!!

Are you attempting to solve the 2005 Putnam A5 integral?
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x + 1)}{x^2 + 1}dx
\end{align}

@NEON it was a question on our vector analysis exam, and I got stuck at this part :)

We can write
$$
2I'(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x^2}\cdot\ln(1 + x^2) + \tan^{-1}x\cdot \frac{2x}{1+x^2}.
$$
Notice any correspondence in the expressions in each term of the sum?

Yes, but it feels like some terms should be swapped thats why I am confused, like the derivative of ln() would give the 2x by chain rule but   Whereas for arctan we would rather not have the 2x term then its simple substitution.

Now i realised that its actually a derivative of arctanx* ln(1+x^2)

I take it you were looking for something of the form $f'f + g'g$ instead of $f'g +g'f$.

A pity I didnt notice it, looks so obvious when you see it:)) thanks!
